# Css and AngularJS : How can I nest two classes in css selector if one class is generated with ng-class

Tags: html, css, angularjs

How can I nest two classes in css selector if one of the class is generated using ng-class in angular js. my code is shown below

```
<input class="form-control class-inputs" ng-class="{'active' : condition here...}" />
<input class="form-control class-inputs" ng-class="{'active' : condition here...}" />
<input class="form-control class-inputs" ng-class="{'active' : condition here...}" />
```

and in my css :

```
.class-inputs.active {
    background-color : red;
 }
```

Problem is the background color is not changing to red.
My goal is to change the color of active button if the condition is true using ng class the color should change to red.

Comment: Are you sure the condition evaluates to `true`? Your CSS is fine.

Answer (score 0):

in your case I think this will work:

```
.active {
  background-color : red;
}
```

Comment: class-inputs .active {
  background-color : red;
}

is not working :(

Comment: no of input will not matter as long as the name of class is same .........the elements which will have the class `active` will become red irrespective of how many they are. it is one of the basic properties of `classes` in html.

Comment: edited the answer...... i missed the starting dot(.) in class `class-inputs`....try now

Comment: I don't believe it will work. You will set the background color to red, on an element that is nested inside of an element with `class-inputs` class.

Comment: i guess you are right..didn't understood the question.....but how about just setting the active class to red....it will make the `background-color: red` to those inputs which have `active` class

Answer (score 0):

```
.class-inputs.active {
    color: red
}
```

refer to css selectors
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html

plunker: http://jsfiddle.net/9pcyy5zc/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
.class-inputs.active{
    background: red;
}
```

Check your condition also for `true`

For your reference check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10653/